# Problema con maven

Tags: java, mysql, maven-compiler-plugin

[![ailed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project atencion-de-citas: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
*Este es el problema que me da al  correr un programa con maven*][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZMVf.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZMVf.png)

Comment: agregale el -e y pon la traza de error, porque como lo tienes ahora podria ser cualquier cosa

Comment: Error al ejecutar el objetivo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) en el proyecto atencion-de-citas: Error en la ejecución del comando.: El proceso finalizó con un error: 1 (Valor de salida: 1) -> [Ayuda 1]  este es el error traducido

Comment: pero llevo un rato intentando solcionar pero no a que se deba este error

Comment: falta la traza, esa sale cuando le pones `-e` a tu comando de maven

Comment: de casualidad me ayudarias remotamente usando  teamveawer o any desk , no se como ver este error

Comment: ya te dije, le debes poner -e cuando corras el comando, si no sabes como crea otra pregunta con lo que hayas intentado para agregar el `-e` aca son la 1 y media de la madrugada asi que no esperes ayuda instantanea

Comment: oooo comprendo vere que puedo solucionar quizas mas tardee me puedas ayudar si no logro solucionar algo y gracias